# How to change Factory girl boolean attribute inside the test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Here is my factory:

```
factory :acceptance do
    favor
    user
    accepted false
  end
```

and here is my request spec:

```
describe "to acceptances" do
    let (:favor) { create(:favor, user: user) }
    let (:acceptance) { create(:acceptance, user: user, favor: favor)}

    context "when has accepted acceptance" do
      it "shold not allow sending more acceptances" do
        acceptance.accepted = true
        expect(permission.allow?(:acceptances, :create, favor)).to be false
      end
```

The problem is with `acceptance.accepted = true`. As I figured out, this is not setting the `accepted` attribute to be `true`. How can I achive this?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: You haven't saved the change?  `acceptance.save` then do the `expect...` line

Comment: Perfect. it worked :) How about you post it as an answer?

Comment: Cool, now posted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the record, otherwise you've only changed the local copy of acceptance. add `acceptance.save` or `update_attribute` will do the save for you.

```
describe "to acceptances" do
  let (:favor) { create(:favor, user: user) }
  let (:acceptance) { create(:acceptance, user: user, favor: favor)}

  context "when has accepted acceptance" do
    it "shold not allow sending more acceptances" do
      acceptance.update_attribute(:accepted, true)
      expect(permission.allow?(:acceptances, :create, favor)).to be false
    end
  end
end
```